# how to clear the link preview after submitting the form in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular-material-extensions/link-preview on textarea. After submitting the form when I again add a character into textarea then it show preview again.

I want to reset it to null or undefined.

Comment: did you using reactive form?

Comment: Yes, I am using reactive form

Comment: so did you use this.FormGroupName.get('textareaformControlName').clear on submit button method?

Comment: The textarea get clear but the preview again appear for a while when I type something.

Comment: can you share the code on  ??

Comment: <mat-form-field class="demo-full-width" appearance="outline" style="width:70%;margin-left:80px;" id="formField">
    <mat-label>Share your thoughts, ideas, or something new...</mat-label>
    <textarea type="text" class="mention form-control"  id="exampleInputEmail1" formControlName="postMessage" matInput matTextareaAutosize matLinkPreview minRows="1"  [(ngModel)]="data" style="max-height: 192px;"></textarea>
    <mat-link-preview-container [hidden]="createPostForm.invalid" multiple="true" [showLoadingsProgress] = false color="primary"></mat-link-preview-container>
</mat-form-field>

Comment: @Abru007 any update for me?

Comment: hi. sorry for the delay i just check every possible way for solving this issue but no way.. for it

Comment: @Abru007 No problem, Thanks for help